# recieving a 404 error when trying to reach certain route

Tags: python, flask, jenkins

I'm pretty new to flask.
I am trying to make some routes for my web app. However I am receiving a 404 error.

[image] my file structure.

this is my routes.py file

```
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from applications import app, db
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return "hi"
```

my app.py file

```
from flask import Flask
from applications import app






if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

my init.py

```
filefrom flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

from applications import routes
```

Can someone please tell me what the issue is?

Comment: what is the output when running the python? what url are you trying to go to?

Comment: I'm trying to go to the /home page.

Comment: and I get a "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." error

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need a separate `routes` file. I would arrange the project structure differently as follows

```
    main.py
    my_application/
        ___init___.py
        templates

    venv
```

main.py

````
```
    import my_application
    app = my_application.create_app()  

    if __name__=='__main__':
        app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```
````

**init**.py

````
```
    from flask import Flask, request

    define create_app():
        app = Flask(__name__)

        @app.route('/')
        @app.route('/home')
        def home():
            return "hi"

        # return the app instance
        return app

```
````